# OpenCV Error 215 src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-h4wtvo23\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

How to solve this error?

Comment: post your code. read the error message carefully. it says what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Always make sure that src contain an image otherwise it give you src.empty() error

```
Syntax: cv2.cvtColor(src, code[, dst[, dstCn]])

Parameters:
src: It is the image whose color space is to be changed.
code: It is the color space conversion code.
dst: It is the output image of the same size and depth as src image. It is an optional parameter.
dstCn: It is the number of channels in the destination image. If the parameter is 0 then the number of the channels is derived automatically from src and code. It is an optional parameter.

Return Value: It returns an image.
```

for examples please see this link [click here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-cvtcolor-method/)